# FFMpeg kmsgrab record pixels in incorrect order

Tags: ffmpeg, video-recording, linux

ffmpeg -f kmsgrab -i - -framerate 60 -vf 'hwdownload,format=bgr0' -preset ultrafast out.mkv

This is how a video frame should look like
[image: kitty terminal emulator in the wayland]
This is how it is recorded by ffmpeg[image: kitty terminal emulator in the wayland][image: weston-simple-egl]
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11jOUTk3ZxOfwnfd7zS4d4qBLApTS3Vmx/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with an intel hd 3000 igpu (i5-2467), but then I lowered the framerate and it was mostly gone, albeit once or twice it bothered me with this image glitch.

The **lower** the **framerate**, the less errors = 15 fps was a good tradeoff I found ; 30fps was smoother but every minute or so I had some milliseconds lost.